# How do I check if I'm connected to database?

Tags: php, mysql, connection, conditional-statements

This is the code to connect to the mysql database:

```
$con = mysql_connect("", "", "");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("", $con);
```

I want to echo 'connected'/'disconnected' depending on state.

How can it be done?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do it Like this

```
if ($con) {
  echo 'connected';
} else {
  echo 'not connected';
}
```

Or try this

```
echo $con ? 'connected' : 'not connected';
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, use the `mysqli_xxx()` functions instead of the old obsolete `mysql_xx()` functions.

This is strongly recommended anyway because the old library is in the process of being deprecated, but will also make your question easier to answer. (you could also use the PDO library, for which the answer will be similar, but for this answer I'll stick with mysqli for simplicity)

With the `mysqli` library, you get a variable that contains your DB connection, which you can examine at any point.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Now, you can query the `$mysqli` variable to find out what is happening.

```
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Later on, you can query the variable using the `ping` command: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php

```
$mysqli->ping();
```

or maybe the `stat` command if you want more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.stat.php

Comment: I'm trying to use Mysqli but I've been unable to go past an error connecting. Do most servers support mysqli? I'm using mediatemple. Thanks

Comment: @Liso22 - I know very little about mediatemplate, but mysqli is a standard part of PHP and has been for a long time. It's also been recommended in preference to the older mysql library for a long time too, so I can't imagine any PHP systems of any quality not supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[mysql_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php)**

> mysql_ping — Ping a server connection or reconnect if there is no
>   connection

something like this should help you

```
if(mysql_ping($con)) 
  echo 'connected'; 
 else 
  echo 'disconnected';
```

Comment: Update: With PHP 5.5 onwards, use [`mysqli_ping()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php)